# Exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, list, exception

I get the below excption:

> Exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The sequence does not contain Elements.

at line

```
var kategoria = db.Kategorie.Include("Kursy").Where(k => k.NazwaKategorii.ToUpper() == nazwaKategori.ToUpper()).Single();
```

My KursyController.cs:

```
using SklepInternetowy1.DAL;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;


namespace SklepInternetowy1.Controllers
{
public class KursyController : Controller
{

    private KursyContext db = new KursyContext();

    // GET: Kursy
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Lista(string nazwaKategori)
    {
        var kategoria = db.Kategorie.Include("Kursy").Where(k => k.NazwaKategorii.ToUpper() == nazwaKategori.ToUpper()).Single();
        var kursy = kategoria.Kursy.ToList();

        return View(kursy);
        //return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Szczegoly(string id)
    {
        var kurs = db.Kursy.ToList();
        return View(kurs);
        //return View();
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult KetagorieMenu()
    {
        var kategorie = db.Kategorie.ToList();
        return PartialView("_KategorieMenu", kategorie);
    }
}
}
```

My Lista.cs

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Lista";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="strona">

@Html.Action("KetagorieMenu")



<img src="../Content/Images/dommaly.png" width="5%" height="5%" />
<a href="link">
    Start > ASP.NET
</a>

@Html.Partial("_KursyList")
```

My _KategorieMenu.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<SklepInternetowy1.Models.Kategoria>
@using SklepInternetowy1.Infrastructure

<tabela>
<wiersz>

    @foreach (var kategoria in Model)
        {
        <komorka>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Lista","Kursy", new { nazwaKategori = kategoria.NazwaKategorii.ToString() })"
               style="background-image: url(@Url.IkonyKategoriiSciezka(kategoria.NazwaPlikuIkony)); ">
                @kategoria.NazwaKategorii
            </a>
        </komorka>
    }
</wiersz>
```

My _KursyList.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<SklepInternetowy1.Models.Kurs>
@using SklepInternetowy1.Infrastructure


<div id="zawartosc">
<tabela>
    <wiersz>
        @foreach (var kurs in Model)
        {

            <komorka>
                <a class="dodajDoKoszykaLink" href="@Url.Action("DodajDoKoszyka","Koszyk",new {id = kurs.KursID})">
                </a>
                @if (kurs.Bestseller)
            {

            }

                <a class="kursSzczegolyLink" href="@Url.Action("Szczegoly","Kursy",new {id =kurs.KursID})">

                    <img class="kurs" src="@Url.ObrazkiSciezka(kurs.NazwaPlikuObrazka)" width="66%" height="66%" />
                    <h1>
                        @kurs.TytulKursu - @kurs.AutorKursu
                    </h1>
                </a>
            </komorka>
        }
    </wiersz>
</tabela>
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this line:

```
var kategoria = db.Kategorie
                  .Include("Kursy")
                  .Where(k => k.NazwaKategorii.ToUpper() == nazwaKategori.ToUpper())
                  .Single();
```

You're calling `.Single()`, which means you're asserting that there is always exactly one record returned in the result.  The error is telling you that *no records* were returned in the result, so the call to `.Single()` fails.

Since it's possible for no records to be returned in the result, instead use `.SingleOrDefault()` and check the result for `null`.  Something like this:

```
var kategoria = db.Kategorie
                  .Include("Kursy")
                  .Where(k => k.NazwaKategorii.ToUpper() == nazwaKategori.ToUpper())
                  .SingleOrDefault();
if (kategoria == null)
{
    // no record was found.
    // handle that situation in whatever way makes sense for your system.
}
```

If it's also possible that *multiple* records can be returned then you'd need to check for that as well, since both `.Single()` and `.SingleOrDefault()` will throw an error for multiple results (as their names imply, really).  Things like `.FirstOrDefault()` or additional `.Where()` clauses, etc. can be helpful to find the record you want in that case.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I was just mid-edit after noticing that myself :)

Comment: if I use .SingleOrDefault() it in a line

var kursy = kategoria.Kursy.ToList();

I have communicat:

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in SklepInternetowy1.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Lukasz: Read the rest of the answer.  You still need to handle the situation where the result is `null`, which is the root of the problem in the first place.

Comment: I am a beginner with programming c #, I use the course: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApAI9eWXIW8)

I did the same as in the video but it does not work. Could you see the viedo and help me?

Comment: @Lukasz: There really aren't many ways to explain this.  Your code is looking for a record in the data that doesn't exist.  So there is no result.  You can't *use* the result when there *is no* result.  So what do you want your code to do when it doesn't find the record it's looking for?  You would write code to do that, whatever that is.

Comment: This code is to retrieve a list of categories from the database and automatically enter the menu categories as you can see here:
http://imgur.com/FZ75C2F

Comment: @Lukasz: And I'm sure it does that *when that category exists*.  But when the category ***doesn't exist*** then the code is failing.  So you need to decide what you want the code to do when the category you're looking for doesn't exist.  I can't tell you what your code is *supposed to do*, that's really up to you.

Comment: it differently:
When I commented out:

  // Var category = db.Kategorie.Include ("Exchange"). Where (k => k.NazwaKategorii.ToUpper () == nazwaKategori.ToUpper ()). Single ();
// Var courses kategoria.Kursy.ToList = ();

It occurs in the line:

@ Html.Action ("KetagorieMenu ')


Exception type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There was an error during the execution of a request sub-module Service 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil + ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper ".


What do I do in this case?

Comment: @Lukasz: Since this case is a completely different error, you should open a new question.  The question you've asked here has already been answered.  I encourage you to take a look at the Tour for Stack Overflow to better understand how this community works: http://stackoverflow.com/tour  This can be a very useful resource, but one thing Stack Overflow can't really do is give you one-on-one guidance and tutoring services.